# Can I apply for a Tier 2 work visa after my Tier 5 Youth Mobility expires?

Tags: united-kingdom, canadian-citizens

I am currently two months into my two year Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa in the UK. Having recently been reading up on the requirements for the Tier 2 General Work Visa, I understand that to "switch" to this visa you would need to currently hold one of the required visas listed.

I don't currently hold one of the required visas, so my question is: If I were to go back to Canada once my two year visa expires, would I be able to apply successfully for the Tier 2 work visa, without having to "switch"?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply if a licensed sponsor has offered you a skilled job in the UK https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general but whether the application would be successful is not something anyone can answer with any certainty.

Comment: To make the answer complete, I will add that going back to Canada is a necessary but not sufficient condition to get a Tier 2 in OP's scenario.